# A cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a degree three splitting field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a cubic polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ with three distinct roots (in $\mathbb{C}$) that has a degree three splitting field?

If $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, with $a,b,c$ distinct, then I believe they must all be real, because otherwise we would get an automorphism of order two (complex conjugation) in $\operatorname{Gal}(f)\cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, contradicting Lagrange's theorem. Now, I can't cook up an example that works, but I'm not sure how to prove nothing does work either. What am I missing?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561108/proving-that-mathbbqx-1-sqrtd-is-the-splitting-field-of-all-irreduc).

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi / 7))$ (embed in the abelian extension $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\Bbb{Q}$)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a cubic polynomial whose discriminant is a square.

E.g. $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1$.

Reference: [the wiki page on cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Galois_group)

Answer (score 2):

Such fields are known as *cyclic* cubic fields, because their Galois group is cyclic of order 3. [Here's the LMFDB's list of cyclic cubic fields](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?galois_group=C3&search_type=List), which includes over four thousand examples.

One easy example (and [the first entry in the list](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.3.49.1)) is the cubic subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/7})$, which has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore has a unique cubic subfield.